# How can I use bert+textcnn model in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Xz_fg62fxZaCIJYdfKtt31uVGWBhoCpr?usp=sharing
I use the Google colab, click this link to see my code.

My question:
When I deal with the `model.fit_generator` ,I have a problem:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 3840

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
15 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 3840
```

Comment: this is my first time to issue my question ,hope everyone could understand my trouble.

Comment: Please post your code here, your link is not accessible